How to share data from a component to another component
I have two components: Home component and product-list component.
This is my home.component.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Products } from '../products';
import { ProductListComponent } from '../product-list/product-list.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ProductListComponent],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrl: './home.component.css'
})
export class HomeComponent {
      // products: Products[] = []
      products: Products[]=[
        {
          "productId": 1,
          "productName": "Leaf Rake",
          "productCode": "GDN-0011",
          "releaseDate": "March 19, 2016",
          "price": 19.95,
          "description": "Leaf Rake with 48-inch wooden handle",
          "starRating": 3.2,
          imageUrl: "./assets/images/Leaf-Rake.png"
        },
        {
          "productId": 2,
          "productName": "Garden Cart",
          "productCode": "GDN-0023",
          "releaseDate": "March 18, 2016",
          "price": 32.99,
          "description": "15 gallon capacity rolling garden cart",
          "starRating": 4.2,
          imageUrl: "./assets/images/garden-cart.png"
        },
        { 
          "productId": 5, 
          "productName": "Hammer", 
          "productCode": "TBX-0048", 
          "releaseDate": "May 21, 2016", 
          "description": "Curved claw steel hammer", 
          "price": 8.9, 
          "starRating": 4.8, 
          "imageUrl": "./assets/images/rejon-Hammer.png" 
        }, 
        { 
          "productId": 8, 
          "productName": "Saw", 
          "productCode": "TBX-0022", 
          "releaseDate": "May 15, 2016", 
          "description": "15-inch steel blade hand saw", 
          "price": 11.55, 
          "starRating": 3.7, 
          "imageUrl": "./assets/images/egore911-saw.png" 
        }, 
        { 
          "productId": 10, 
          "productName": "Video Game Controller", 
          "productCode": "GMG-0042", 
          "releaseDate": "October 15, 2015", 
          "description": "Standard two-button video game controller", 
          "price": 35.95, 
          "starRating": 4.6, 
          "imageUrl": "./assets/images/xbox-controller.png" 
        }
      ]
  searching: string = '';//khởi tạo searching kiểu string có giá trị null
  filterProductList: Products[] = []// khởi tạo biến filterProductList

  ngOnInit(): void{
    //Called after the constructor, initializing input properties, and the first call to ngOnChanges.
    //Add 'implements OnInit' to the class.
    this.filterProductList = this.products;
  }
  constructor(){
    this.filterProductList = this.products;   
  }
  filterResults(){
    console.log(this.searching);
    if(!this.searching){
      this.filterProductList = this.products;
    }
      //lọc this.products dựa trên tên sản phẩm
      this.filterProductList = this.products.filter(
      list => list?.productName.toLowerCase().includes(this.searching.toLowerCase())
    )
  }
}

This is my product-list.component.ts
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Products } from '../products';
import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ProductListComponent],
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrl: './product-list.component.css'
})

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [HomeComponent, CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrl: './product-list.component.css'
})
export class ProductListComponent {
  @Input() productlist: Products[] = [];
}


I'm trying display <app-product-list> in home.component.html but there was an error said:
"'app-product-list' is not a known element:

If 'app-product-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is included in the '@Component.imports' of this component.
If 'app-product-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.ngtsc(-998001)"

This is my home.component.html codes:
<div class="row-mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <!-- <label for="searching">Tìm sản phẩm</label> -->
                <input type="text" size="50" [(ngModel)]="searching" 
            (ngModelChange)="filterResults()" name="searching"
            class="input form-control" placeholder="Tìm sản phẩm"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-3 pl-3 pr-3">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Available</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>5 star Rating</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let item of filterProductList">
                <td scope="row"><img src="{{item.imageUrl}}" width="50px" alt=""></td>
                <td>{{item.productName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.productCode}}</td>
                <td>{{item.releaseDate}}</td>
                <td>{{item.price}}</td>
                <td>{{item.starRating}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<app-product-list></app-product-list>

Finally, I would like to say thank you to the person who viewed this post. If there is anything wrong with my English, code, or posting. Tell me, thank you so much.

can you please make stackbliz link that is more easy for others to understand

Remove "HomeComponent" from the import array of the product-list components as it is not needed. Additionally, please pass products as input and try re-running the code. If the error persists, kindly provide a StackBlitz link for further investigation

I think there are some syntax mistakes in your code.

In product-list.component.ts you have added two component tags. You have to remove @Component tag which have selector value of app-home.
To use product-list component in home.component.html you have to include tag like this : <app-product-list [productlist]="filterProductList"></app-product-list>
Here I am assuming that you want to pass filterProductList of home component as a input to product list component. also you have to implement life-cycle hooks of angular in both product-list and home component (OnInit & OnChanges in product-list and OnInit in home component).


He is using standalone so no need to add to a module

Sorry missed that! thanks for correcting

Your product-list.component.ts seems to have two @Component Tags. 
First, remove the wrong one. (This one)
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ProductListComponent],
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrl: './product-list.component.css'
})

Then you can also remove the HomeComponent import from the ProductListComponent:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrl: './product-list.component.css'
})

Your Code should work fine, without the doubled @Component Tag.
